# Override entity form handler

Tags: 8

I'm trying to alter an entity form handler. The method [EntityType::setHandlerClass()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityType.php/function/EntityType%3A%3AsetHandlerClass/8.8.x) allows for the 'form' handler to be set, but this value is an array, and I only want to override a single item of the array.

The entity handlers definition:

```
handlers = {
    "storage" = "Drupal\user\UserStorage",
    "storage_schema" = "Drupal\user\UserStorageSchema",
    "access" = "Drupal\user\UserAccessControlHandler",
    "list_builder" = "Drupal\user\UserListBuilder",
    "views_data" = "Drupal\user\UserViewsData",
    "route_provider" = {
      "html" = "Drupal\user\Entity\UserRouteProvider",
    },
    "form" = {
      "default" = "Drupal\user\ProfileForm",
      "cancel" = "Drupal\user\Form\UserCancelForm",
      "register" = "Drupal\user\RegisterForm"
    },
    "translation" = "Drupal\user\ProfileTranslationHandler"
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out how to override the form.register handler, but as the first argument to setEntityHandler() is a string, I cannot figure out how to set a nested value.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. Instead of using [EntityType::setHandlerClass()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityType.php/function/EntityType%3A%3AsetHandlerClass/8.8.x), use [EntityType::setFormClass()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityType.php/function/EntityType%3A%3AsetFormClass/8.8.x).

Comment: Curious to know, where did you put this code inside of?

Comment: hook_entity_type_alter()